# Grid cuts my images

Tags: bugs, front-end, output-formatting, image, grid-layouts

**Bug introduced in V9.0 or earlier and persisting through V11.2**

---

```
pic2 = ImageResize[
  ImageCrop@Rasterize@Graphics@Disk[],
  {Automatic, 40}]
```

> [image]

```
Grid[{{pic2}}]
```

> [image]

This is just annoying...

Win 10 V10.3.1

**Q:** so, is there any quick fix? Have I missed something obvious?

p.s. e.g. `Row` works well but it is not `Grid` :-)

---

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3522370] was created:
>
> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> I have filed a report regarding the behavior you describe. The appropriate development team will be able to review the issue and hopefully implement a fix in a future version.
>
> Fortunately this is not an issue with the object itself, but with its visual representation in the Mathematica front end. Although not a practical workaround, if you increase your magnification from 100% to 200%, you will notice the problem no longer persists. Similarly, if I printed the notebook demonstrating the issue I did not experience the clipping.
>
> If you are able to get away without using ImageCrop, the issue does not seem to present itself. Without seeing your actual application it is difficult to provide a solution that will work in any scenario and still maintain the exact results you desire.

---

Comment: Grid[{{pic2}}, Frame -> All] clips the left side too.  However, this can be repaired with `Spacings`.  Unfortunately, `Spacings does not repair the original problem; e.g., `Grid[{{pic2}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey this is just ridiculous :-/

Comment: This does remove the clips but not sure about the method `First@Grid[{{pic2}}]`

Comment: @Hubble07  Yes, but it also removes the `Grid`.

Comment: @Hubble07 let's go further and turn off the screen :p

Comment: Removing ImageCrop works correctly... Strangely magnifying bigger than 1 also corrects it...

Comment: @s.s.o take `pic2` as given, e.g. from web page. And I suppose it doesn't work, just the difference isn't visible due to the white frame.

Comment: @s.s.o yep, on different magnification levels it looks beter, not the same though, If you take a closer look, the first row is different.

Comment: The image from `Grid[{{pic2}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Background -> Blue]` shows that the circle is not centered vertically in `Grid`, and `Alignment` has no effect.  Even stranger, if you execute `Grid[{{pic2}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Background -> Blue]` again on the next line, the first image changes!

Comment: I'mu using version 10.3.0 Linux, and this does not happen, `Grid` shows the circle correctly with or without the `Frame` option

Comment: Let's keep the bug description on a single line so that Pickett's script can extract it.  If you want to display a line break, `<br>` works without needing to put an empty line in the markdown source.

Comment: @Szabolcs ok! I was not aware of that, what script? p.s. I have to edit couple of topics now :)

Comment: @Kuba The one linked [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1610/12).  I think the WRI QA folks found that very useful because it is able to filter out fixed bugs.  It extracts the first "paragraph" (i.e. up to the first empty line) of the markdown and looks for the word "fixed" in it, I think (but I didn't look at the source code).  It also generates a nice webpage with links to each topic and the "bug line" included in the summary.

Answer (score 12):

With `Frame -> All`, the automatic `Spacings` are weird. The automatic `BaselinePosition` is bad either way.

It seems to be a good idea to include substitutes for as many of those options which are `Automatic` by default as possible:

```
pic2 = ImageResize[ImageCrop@Rasterize@Graphics@Disk[], {Automatic, 40}];

Grid[{{pic2}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {0, 0},
               BaselinePosition -> Center, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: When you put another `Grid` on that, the feature is back. It would be so nice to not have to care where the inner grid ends up.

Comment: `Grid@List@List@%`

Comment: `Grid` is terrible. I used this solution but then some glitches were introduced in the interior of the image, unfortunately, I can't share that image and I wasn't able to reproduce that problem with `Graphics`. That's crazy.

Comment: @Kuba [Don't I know it.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+[bugs]+[grid]) :-p

Comment: Due to all those issues I'm using in my UI `ImagePad[pic2, 1, 1]` or whichever value that fits the background. If such row is cut it's not a harm.